# Read data from DB in Tasklet oriented Batch process

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a simple question. I have to code a Tasklet oriented Spring Batch project which have to retrieve some data from DB, process info. and write it into a .json file. I´m using Spring Data JPA, but is this the correct and safest way to do this?
If not, what is the best way to code this?
Thanks a lot for you help!

Latest Tasklet reader code:

```
public class DataReader implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

@Autowired
EntityRepository entityRepository;

@Autowired
ProductRepository productRepository;

@Autowired
SuscriptionRepository suscriptionRepository;

@Autowired
MapperUtils mapperUtils;

private List<EntityDTO> entityDataDTO;

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {        
    this.entityDataDTO = new ArrayList<EntityDTO>();
    List<Entidad> entities = entityRepository.findAll();

    for (Entidad entity : entities) {
        List<SuscriptionDTO> suscriptionsDTO = new ArrayList<SuscriptionDTO>();

        for (Suscripcion suscription : entity.getSuscripciones()) {
            List<Suscripcion> suscriptionsByProduct = suscriptionRepository.findSuscriptionsByEntityIdAndSuscriptionId(suscription.getId().getIdEntidadEurbt(), suscription.getId().getIdSuscripcion());
            List<String> suscriptionProducts = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (Suscripcion suscriptionProduct : suscriptionsByProduct) {
                Producto product = productRepository.findById(suscriptionProduct.getId().getIdProductoEurbt()).get();
                suscriptionProducts.add(product.getTlDescProducto());
            }

            SuscriptionDTO suscriptionDTO = mapperUtils.mapSuscriptionDataToSuscriptionDTO(suscription, suscriptionProducts);

            if (!suscriptionsDTO.contains(suscriptionDTO)) 
                suscriptionsDTO.add(suscriptionDTO);

        }

        this.entityDataDTO.add(mapperUtils.mapEntityDataToEntityDTO(entity, suscriptionsDTO));
    }

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("entityDataDTO", this.entityDataDTO); 
    return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Tasklet` to read, process and write the whole dataset is is not the best way as there will be only one transaction for the whole dataset. A [chunk-oriented step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) is more appropriate for your use case. With chunk oriented processing, there will be one transaction for each chunk.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know that, but client company gave me a custom maven archetype which generates a tasket oriented project, so I have to work this way